# Why is force:inputField bound to the lookup Account.ParentId creating error-popups?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, app-builder, flexipages

Using force:inputField bound to Account.ParentId on a flexipage, I get a sequence of ugly error-popups. However after closing a couple of popus, the component feels usable.

I think it is related to that part of the error messages `AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'inContextOfRecordId'` - but I've not used that directly, so I can't figure the backgrounds...

**Error looks like this:**

[image]

**Component**

```
<aura:component access="global"  
    controller="testUwe_LC"
    implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" 
>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account' }"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <force:inputField aura:id="itemName" value="{!v.item.ParentId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**js-controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getItem");
        action.setParams({
          "id": component.get("v.recordId"),
        });
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.item", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);        
    },
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class testUwe_LC { 
    @AuraEnabled public static Account getItem(Id id) {
        return [select Id, Name, ParentId from Account where Id = :id ][0];
    }
}
```

**Full Error code (displayed as "Technical Stuff")**

```
Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'inContextOfRecordId' of component 'markup://c:testUwe {1:994;a}' is not visible to 'markup://c:testUwe {1:994;a}'.
Logger.prototype.error@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:3752:9
AuraInstance.prototype.error@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17377:3
AttributeSet.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8679:9
Component.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:5718:14
PropertyReferenceValue.prototype.evaluate@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:4196:17
AttributeSet.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8710:13
Component.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:5718:14
PropertyReferenceValue.prototype.evaluate@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:4196:17
AttributeSet.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8710:13
Component.prototype.get@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:5718:14
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktopDataProvider.helper.provide@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:43551:23
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktopDataProvider.controller.provide@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:43509:9
Action.prototype.$runDeprecated$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8197:24
Component$getActionCaller@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6454:7
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlerIterator$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7830:9
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlers$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7808:3
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7860:5
AuraInstance.prototype.$run$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17571:12
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7858:3
ui$autocompleteList.helper.fireDataProvideEvent@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:17381:9
ui$autocompleteList.controller.fetchData@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:17285:9
Action.prototype.$runDeprecated$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8197:24
Component$getActionCaller@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6454:7
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlerIterator$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7830:9
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlers$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7808:3
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7860:5
AuraInstance.prototype.$run$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17571:12
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7858:3
Component.prototype.$getMethodHandler$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6432:5
ui$autocomplete.helper.fetchData@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:24010:13
ui$autocomplete.controller.fetchData@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:23886:9
Action.prototype.$runDeprecated$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8197:24
Component$getActionCaller@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6454:7
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlerIterator$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7830:9
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlers$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7808:3
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7860:5
AuraInstance.prototype.$run$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17571:12
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7858:3
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktop.helper.fetchData@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:47609:9
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktop.helper.openPopup@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:48343:13
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktop.helper.inputFocused@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:48326:13
forceSearch$inputLookupDesktop.controller.inputFocus@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:47040:9
Action.prototype.$runDeprecated$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8197:24
Component$getActionCaller@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6454:7
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlerIterator$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7830:9
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlers$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7808:3
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7860:5
AuraInstance.prototype.$run$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17571:12
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7858:3
lib/lib.fireEvent@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:121778:17
ui$input.helper.fireEvent@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:2354:9
ui$autocomplete.controller.handleFocus@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:23902:13
Action.prototype.$runDeprecated$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:8197:24
Component$getActionCaller@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:6454:7
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlerIterator$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7830:9
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$executeHandlers$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7808:3
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7860:5
AuraInstance.prototype.$run$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17571:12
Aura.$Event$.$Event$.prototype.$fire$@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:7858:3
lib/lib.fireEvent@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:121778:17
ui$input.helper.fireEvent@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:2354:9
lib/lib.domEventHandler@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%220aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22us4xuMp_piK81qoJxBigpg%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22de%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_GB%22%2C%22de_CH%22%2C%22ja_JP%22%2C%22ja%22%2C%22en_NZ%22%2C%22de_AT%22%2C%22cs_CZ%22%2C%22cs%22%2C%22fr_FR%22%2C%22fr%22%2C%22de_DE%22%2C%22en_US%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:121755:17
AuraInstance.prototype.$getCallback$/<@https://xe301-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/0aX-jfAXPggJFRoObqLaSQ/aura_proddebug.js:17464:14
```

Comment: Yikes! That's a lot of error to code to try muck thru Uwe! @DougChasman Please look at this post.

Comment: Can you try after turning debug mode off in lightning components.

Comment: Try wrapping your callback function in $A.getCallback() to preserve component access context.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been logged with Salesforce as a known issue.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eaxfQAA

The issue seems to be with force:inputField component for a lookup field with the debug mode enabled. The proposed workaround is to disable the debug mode. There are some known issues associated with the force:inputField component still.

Another minor point, the *recordId* needs to be specified before the remote call or will throw an apex error (list index out of bounds).